# justify-content: space-around; Not Working in Caret

Tags: html, css

My code is below. I'm using Caret on Chromebook OS. Is there a way I can still use this code? The [space] part highlights but once I type [-around] the highlighting disappears. I hope this explains my issue well. If you can help me please do, this is for school!

```html
<!DOCType html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-sclae=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    
    <title>Registered Nursing</title>
    
    <style>
      body {
        background-color:rgb(175, 213, 252);
      }
      
      
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
      
    </style>
    
    <title>Home Page</title>
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <header class="tc-header">
      <div class="tcc-container">
        <div style="text-align:left" class="tc-logo">
          <img src="rnlogo.png" alt="Logo"
          style="width:200px;height:200px">
        </div>
        <nav class="tc-nav">
          <li> <a href="#">Home align</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Education</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> More Info</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Usage</a></li>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  <strong><header style="color:White;">A Highly Respected Career</header></strong>
  <h1 style="color:rgb(175,213, 252);">Registred Nursing</h1>
  


  
  <img src="talking.jpg" alt="Group of Nurses Talking" class="center"
  style="width:704px;height:421px">
  
 <font size="4"><strong><p> A registered nurse is a nurse that has passed the NCLEX-RN exam, and achieved their certification. They're elgible to work in many different departments such as the ER, mental health unit, schools, and so much more. Continue to explore this site to found out more!</p></strong></font>
  
  <a href="Education.html">2 |</a>
  <a href="TasksandSalary">3 | </a>
  <a href="How.html">4 |</a>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:87px;
  background-color:White;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

p {
  color:White;
}

a href {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62%;
}

.tc-header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.tc-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tc-logo img {
  width: 5rem;
}

.tc-nav {
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;
}
```

I tried putting text-alignment on the index.html and on the CSS neither has worked. If you notice other issues feel free to make me aware of them!

Comment: Your class name in the HTML file is wrong. It should be `tc-container`, not `tcc-container` because it is defined as `.tc-container` in your CSS file

Comment: Also, I will add a few corrections to your code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, **your class names do not match**. It is defined in **HTML** as `.tcc-container` but in the CSS file, it is `tc-container`.

**So match the names and your styles will work.**

For other corrections to your code:

- **font is a deprecated HTML element, do not use it for styling your text**. Instead, use the `style` attribute or define a `class` with properties like `font-size`, `font-family`, etc
- **`a href` is not a valid CSS selector.** Instead style with just `a` to target all anchor elements, or define a `class`.

Other good practices:

- While `<strong>` is the HTML element to make text bold, it is not a wrapper element so putting a `<p>` element as its child is not semantically correct. **So, remove all `strong` elements used as wrappers and instead, style `<p>` to have bold text.** In this case, I have defined a class `.tc-p` and added it to all your elements that match the case.

**NOTE:** I have not added the corrected codes so you can spot the errors yourself with these suggestions, that will help you learn better.

I'll update this answer if I spot anything else. Good luck with school!